# CORS with Express.js and jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, cors

I use express.js for my server, with this headers:

```
x-powered-by: Express
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 2
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
access-control-allow-methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: x-requested-with
```

I call `res.header` to allow CORS:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");  
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

*You can test here : http://my-api.rs.af.cm/api/products*

For my front-end, I use jsbin and I call my server with `$.ajax`: http://jsbin.com/apizez/37/edit

*Result here: http://jsbin.com/apizez/37*

You can look at the JS console, you will see this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my-api.rs.af.cm/api/products. Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I read all others answers on CORS and I don't want to use easyXDM.

Comment: Are all of your requests passing those headers back? Do you have support for the Preflight OPTIONS request?

Comment: Just looked and yes, Chrome is doing a preflight OPTIONS request which isn't getting any of the CORS headers back. Fix that you will have this licked.

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests

Comment: I added the headers in OPTIONS requests and I set `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"` to `"content-Type,x-requested-with,origin,accept"`.
But It still not working, you can see in the examples on my posts.

Comment: In the Chrome JavaScript console, there is `OPTIONS http://my-api.jit.su/api/products 200 (OK)`, but it's display like an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Ryan Olds to help me to understand how CORS requests work.

Here the correct headers:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-Type,x-requested-with');
```

All my requests had that headers in their response.

I use `$.getJSON` for GET requests with jQuery, otherwise It doesn't work.

You can see the example here:
http://jsbin.com/uwevuc/2/edit

http://jsbin.com/uwevuc/2

Comment: Note that `*` will not work in most cases (for details check simple vs. preflight request in the spec), you need to mention your domain explicitly in the allow-origin header. Also, there is no need to allow OPTIONS nor standard headers like content-type or origin, they are allowed by default.

Comment: I edited my post to add origin request explicity, thanks. For the header, I need to specify "content-type", otherwise I've this error: `Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.` but indeed, we don't need to have origin and accept.

Comment: True enough, content-type can only be omitted for certain standard types such as text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

You must take in consideration your preflight request also. I suggest you to add the "cors" npm package on your project, and start it with this following configurations:

```js
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH , 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    origin: true
});
```

This will enable Cross Origin Requests for any address with the listed methods. The origin parameter is very flexible, you can delimiter a set of address, all address or by regex, for example. Here is the package docs:

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html